# Create an event for a DateTimePicker that was created programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I created a DateTimePicker programmatically like this:

```
Controls.Add(new DateTimePicker { Name = "txtPaymentDate", 
                                  Location = new Point(146, 232),
                                  Size = new Size(113, 20),
                                  Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom,
                                  CustomFormat = " ", TabStop = false });
```

If the DateTimePicker is not open it won't have a default date. But I want to change the DateTime format whenever I select a date using the **CloseUp Event**. However, since the DateTimePicker was created manually I don't know how to create the event for it.

How can I create the event for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create an event handler for control created programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972357/create-an-event-handler-for-control-created-programmatically)

Comment: You could search through the ``Controls`` collection until you find one with the matching name, and then attach your delegates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
DateTimePicker myPicker = new DateTimePicker { Name = "txtPaymentDate", 
                                               Location = new Point(146, 232), 
                                               Size = new Size(113, 20), 
                                               Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom, 
                                               CustomFormat = " ", 
                                               TabStop = false };
myPicker.CloseUp += myPicker_CloseUp;

Controls.Add(myPicker);

private void myPicker_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is DateTimePicker)
    {
       ((DateTimePicker)sender).Format = 'dd-MM-yyyy'; 
    }
}
```

if you want the event only do stuff for specific DateTimePicker (by name) you can do this :

```
private void myPicker_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is DateTimePicker)
    {
       if (DateTimePicker)sender).Name == "txtPaymentDate")
           ((DateTimePicker)sender).Format = 'dd-MM-yyyy'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: But how can I indicate in the CloseUp event the name of the DateTimePicker to change the format to: 'dd-MM-yyyy' ?

Comment: @ErrolChavesMoya Yes you can, I edited my answer to show how you can do that

Comment: You are my hero! thank you so much, just what I needed; it worked.